# Initialize polars dataframe from list of structs

Tags: python, python-polars

These two make sense:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=1,
  ))
print(df)
print(df.schema)

 j
 1
shape: (1, 1)
{'j': Int64}

df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=range(2)
  ))
print(df)
print(df.schema)
  
 j
 0
 1
shape: (2, 1)
{'j': Int64}
```

However:

```
cols = list('ab')

df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=polars.struct([polars.lit(j).alias(col) for j, col in enumerate(cols)], eager=True)
  ))
print(df)
print(df.schema)

 j
 {0,1}
shape: (1, 1)
{'j': Struct([Field('a', Int32), Field('b', Int32)])}

df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=[polars.struct([polars.lit(j).alias(col) for j, col in enumerate(cols)], eager=True)
    for k in range(2)]
  ))
print(df)
print(df.schema)

 j
 [{0,1}]
 [{0,1}]
shape: (2, 1)
{'j': List(Struct([Field('a', Int32), Field('b', Int32)]))}
```

Why did changing from a single `polars.struct` to a list of `polar.struct`s change the type of the element itself (from `Struct` to `List(Struct)`)? I'd expect the result of the last one above to be the same as this:

```
df = (polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=range(2)
  ))
  .with_columns(
    polars.struct([polars.lit(j).alias(col) for j, col in enumerate(cols)], eager=True).alias('j')
    ))
print(df)
print(df.schema)

 j
 {0,1}
 {0,1}
shape: (2, 1)
{'j': Struct([Field('a', Int32), Field('b', Int32)])}
```

Is there a shorter / better way to initialize the dataframe with a list of structs (i.e. a shorter way to get the same result as the last code example above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pl.struct` with `eager=True` returns a Series object.

```
>>> type(pl.struct(a=0, b=1, eager=True))
polars.series.series.Series
```

To simplify things, it may help to look at it as:

```
>>> struct = [dict(a=0, b=1)]
>>> struct
[{'a': 0, 'b': 1}]
```

Your first example passes the "struct" directly:

```
>>> pl.DataFrame({"col": struct})
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ col       │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {0,1}     │
└───────────┘
```

The outer `[]` is treated as the container of rows, and each item inside is a single row.

Your second example passes a list of "structs":

```
pl.DataFrame({"col": [struct, struct]})
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ col             │
│ ---             │
│ list[struct[2]] │
╞═════════════════╡
│ [{0,1}]         │
│ [{0,1}]         │
└─────────────────┘
```

Each "struct" is treated as a single row, which has its `[]` intact.

If you have a list of series objects, perhaps you're looking to `.concat` them, it's not entirely clear.

```
pl.concat([
    pl.struct(a=0, b=1, eager=True),
    pl.struct(a=0, b=1, eager=True)
]).to_frame("col")
```

```
shape: (2, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ col       │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {0,1}     │
│ {0,1}     │
└───────────┘
```